# How to add ads in flutter flame

Tags: flutter, dart, admob, flame

Like we have sprite to add/render images in flutter flame. Is their any widget or any way to show ads(admob) in flutter flame project.

Answer (score 3):

Since Flame is just another Flutter widget you can use the [firebase_admob](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_admob) or any other ads package, just like it would have been used in any Flutter app. There is good documentation of how to use the admob flutter widgets in their [readme](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/).

If you want to display an ad on top of the game I suggest that you either use a Stack widget or use the [overlays](https://flame-engine.org/docs/#/game?id=flutter-widgets-and-game-instances) system in Flame.